# Convert storage macro from frame v1 to frame v2

Tags: substrate, parity

The title is very descriptive.

I would like to convert this:

```
decl_storage! {
    trait Store for Module<T: Config> as SimpleTreasury {
        // No storage items of our own, but we still need decl_storage to initialize the pot
    }
    add_extra_genesis {
        build(|_config| {
            // Create the charity's pot of funds, and ensure it has the minimum required deposit
            let _ = T::Currency::make_free_balance_be(
                &<Module<T>>::account_id(),
                T::Currency::minimum_balance(),
            );
        });
    }
}
```

into frame V2. Below I have my converted version but it seems not working, the minimum balance seems not being set correctly.

```
#[pallet::genesis_config]
    #[derive(Default)]
    pub struct GenesisConfig {

    }

    #[pallet::genesis_build]
    impl<T: Config> GenesisBuild<T> for GenesisConfig {
        fn build(&self) {
            let _ = T::Currency::make_free_balance_be(
                &<Module<T>>::account_id(),
                T::Currency::minimum_balance(),
            );
        }
    }
```

Can somebody take a look and tell me what's wrong. I would really appreciate it.
Pallet Github link: https://github.com/herou/recipes/tree/recipes_pallet_v2/pallets/charity
Note: Some tests are failing

Comment: Please post text as text, not as images of text.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what specifically "seems not working" means?

Comment: The title is **not** very descriptive: v1 and v2 of what? Storage of what?

Comment: @ScottHunter I did it, thank you

Comment: @IMSoP Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `pallet` macro has a section about upgrading from `decl_*` macros: https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/latest/frame_support/attr.pallet.html#upgrade-guidelines

I advise to read carefully the section.

To say few points of this doc I can say:

1. there is a helper inside `decl_storage` to generate some code for the new pallet macro. By running the macro expansion with the environment variable `PRINT_PALLET_UPGRADE`: e.g. `PRINT_PALLET_UPGRADE=1 cargo check -p $my_pallet$`.
2. The pallet prefix that the storage use is configured differently: in decl_storage the pallet prefix is given (e.g. `SimpleTreasury` in your example). Now the pallet prefix is the name configured when constructing the runtime. (e.g. in construct_runtime call, when it is written: `MyPalletName: path_to_pallet::{Call, ...},`, the name `MyPalletName`). If the name are different you can use some utility function to create a migration: https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/latest/frame_support/storage/migration/index.html
3. The attributes `config()` and `build()` that put specific values into the storage should now be put into the `GenesisConfig::build` implementation.
4. Usually the hashers and types to use when declaring the storage should be quite straightforward. But people must be careful about the `QueryKind` generic. If the storage was written with a value `Option<$Something>` then the querykind is an [OptionQuery](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/latest/frame_support/storage/types/struct.OptionQuery.html), otherwise it is a [ValueQuery](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/latest/frame_support/storage/types/struct.ValueQuery.html). (but the helper with `PRINT_PALLET_UPGRADE` must give you the correct translation.)